# How can i change language through html of webpage

Tags: php, html, cookies

```
var $language = 'es_ES';
// en_US
// es_ES
```

how can i change language through HTML with "links"

through HTML this works, but when i go to another webpage it disappears &lang=es_ES

```
http://exemplewebpage.com/?action=clients&lang=es_ES
http://exemplewebpage.com/?action=clients&lang=en_US
```

Comment: You might want to use a session and store the language there, each page will use language from the session

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249159/best-practice-multi-language-website) could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may say

```
<a href="homepage.php?lang='es_ES'">
<a href="homepage.php?lang='fr_FR'">
```

and then

```
if ( !empty($_GET['lang']) ) 
    $_COOKIE['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
 else 
    $_COOKIE['language'] = 'some_default_language';

setcookie('language', $_COOKIE['lang']);
```

Or you might use `$_SESSION` if you don't want it to persist for the user.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, you have to use session variables.

Of course, you will have to start the session by using the php function `session_start()` and when the language is selected (i.e `&lang=es_ES`) you will have to initialize the session variable like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
   $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}
```

from here on, the session will remain set with that value on whatever page you go trough...

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: but how can i implement it in homepage link to change the language??

Comment: what exactly do you mean by implement in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

The way i understand it you should try used

```
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
if($lang == 'es_ES'){
var $language = 'es_ES';
} else if($lang == 'en_US'){
var $language = 'en_US';
}
```

Maybe this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Given that:

```
$language = $_GET['lang'];
```

Pass the lang='.$language.' in every `href="...&lang='` as well as hidden fields in forms when making GET request

```
<hidden name="lang" value="<?=$language?>"/>
```

and  when making POST request).

```
<form method="POST" action="...&lang=<?=$language?>">
```

But it might be better to use a session.

At the beginning of your document:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['language'])) {
    //Pick a default language
    $_SESSION['language'] = "es_ES";
}
//check if there is an override 
if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] != "") {
    $_SESSION['language'] = $_GET['lang'];
}
```

Now in your business logic you can refer to it as:

```
if($_SESSION['language'] == "es_ES") {
    //do whatever
} else if ($_SESSION['language'] == "en_US") {
    //HAHA I'm speaking english
}
```

Good luck!

Depending on your requirements you may wish to use cookies rather then sessions.

Comment: but how can i set lang through home.php or how can client set lang of session?

Comment: This is why you have a default language. If the session isn't set the default language is "es_ES". (This is what the first if statement does). If you want to change the session, all you have to do is have on your website a button/link with the following: <code>href=home.php?lang=fr_FR</code> or whatever language you want. This is what the second if statement does. It checks whether $_GET['lang'] is present in your URL if it is we are going to use it

Comment: Thanks +1 dude, i did it with Session and it worked :)

Comment: if(!isset($_SESSION['language'])) {
      $_SESSION['language'] = "ca_ES";
  }
  if(isset($this->url->lang) && $this->url->lang != "") {
      $_SESSION['language'] = $this->url->lang;
  }

  $this->language=$_SESSION['language'];