# Multi Language Application PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, translation

I created an extensive web application (+500K lines) in PHP CSS HTML JQUERY and I want to translated to English and Portuguese. I have been struggling with the question about, what is the best and most efficient way to do this. What I have thought so far is doing a es.php en.php and po.php file which contain something like this.

```
$lang['qty'] = "Qty"; //10
$lang['product'] = "Producto"; //10
$lang['price'] = "Precio"; //10
$lang['total'] = "Total"; //10
```

Then include the respective file in php and echo out the variable. The problem with this is that the file will be 3000 lines and I feel that there has to be another way.

I was wondering if you could help me with this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its not an uncommon approach i have seen in several projects. i would not discount it out of hand

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249159/best-practice-multi-language-website) :)