# Internalization of a website - Best rules

Tags: php, internationalization

I'm using PHP.

I've a system that I need to translate in french, italian, spanish, ...

So I came with two solutions.

**Solution 1:**
All the language strings are store in a DB to allow easy editing after for the administrator. So on each page I will need to call this table in order to get the correct strings.

**Solution 2:**
Same like the first one except that I will generate after each change a Json file. This Json file will be call on each page to print the right strings.

Witch of my solution is the best pleas ?

Perhaps, another solution exists for that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice multi language website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249159/best-practice-multi-language-website)

Comment: Is the system based on any framework?

Comment: @Edu: No. It's in full PHP.

Comment: This is a huge huge huge topic.  It can't be answered in a SO post.

Answer (score 1):

I once did a project with multiple languages. It was a big hassle. I am not recommending my method below, but showing it to you as an example of how it can be achieved.

lang.en.php

```
$lang = array();

$lang['menu'] = array(
  'home'     => 'Home',
  'projects' => 'Projects',
  'about'    => 'About',
  'contact'  => 'Contact'
);

$lang['some_other_section'] = array(
  'some_value' => 'some value',
  ...
  ...
);
```

lang.no.php

```
$lang = array();

$lang['menu'] = array(
  'home'     => 'Hjem',
  'projects' => 'Prosjekter',
  'about'    => 'Om',
  'contact'  => 'Kontakt'
);

$lang['some_other_section'] = array(
  'some_value' => 'En annen verdi',
  ...
  ...
);
```

Now, the big hassle was to write all the text in the application using variables, then add them and translate in each language file.

index.php

```
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#"><?php echo $lang['menu']['home']; ?></a>
  <a href="#"><?php echo $lang['menu']['projects']; ?></a>
  <a href="#"><?php echo $lang['menu']['about']; ?></a>
  <a href="#"><?php echo $lang['menu']['contact']; ?></a>
</div>
```

You would have to set the "active" language some place in the initialization of the page. i.e:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if($_SESSION['lang'] == "en") {

    require('lang.en.php');

  } elseif($_SESSION['lang'] == "no") {

    require('lang.no.php');

  }

?>
<html>
<head>
 ...
 ...
```

Comment: use a switch statement on your session rather than if, makes it more manageable

Comment: Sure thing. It was just for explicitly explaining the example code.

Comment: still a good example, you should revamp it into an OOP approach and use a database rather than loads of php files ;) voted up though

Comment: If I ever do need to go multilingual again, I will definitely look into it. I guess it will be a hassle any way you approach it. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: Thanks for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use a database: you can hold questions and answers in a table that has each language answer in columns - its simple enough to then set up an RBAC module to allow specific users to add new questions and answers.

```
questions_table:
    question_id (int) 255 PK AUTO_INCREMENT
    question (varchar) 160

answers_table:
    answer_id (int) 255 PK AUTO_INCREMENT
    question_id (int) 255
    language_id (int) 255
    answer (varchar)

language_table:
    language_id (int) 255 PK AUTO_INCREMENT
    language (varchar) 30

user table and user answer table also
```

using this, you'll be able to reference between tables using `INNER JOIN` sql statements, then all you need to do is create a driver object for your connection (preferably pdo) and then objects for answering questions, logging in, registering, admin and a front end display.